# php using imap_fetchbody my app on iis does not fetch html

Tags: php, html, imap

I have a php web app that I am building a receive all function.
I created the app on Dev environment on xampp and when I used imap_fetchbody using option 1.2 (HTML) it reads the HTML nicely.
However I have now put the app into production on a windows server using iis- exactly the same code, however it will not get HTML content, it just shows blank. When I change to 1.1 (plain text) the body is fetched (but looks crap as there are no line breaks etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason when I use 2 as the email part instead of 1 it works. 
Strange that the same emails were in different parts for apache and iis.

```
imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $emailNum, 2)
```

the above works, I've actually done this:

```
$body = (imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$emailNum,1.2))?imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$emailNum,1.2):imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$emailNum,2);
```

Comment: You shouldn't hard code the part number.  The parts move depending on what software sent the email, whether it has attachments, etc.  You should be getting the body structure to find out where the parts are.

Comment: Thanks Max, how do you do that?

Comment: Start with imap_fetchstructure.  You should be able to find examples here and elsewhere.  It will also help you know what kind of encoding/decoding you need to apply to your parts.